# saving form data permanently

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to save html form data permanently inside a file or some other place where we can use it later.I know this is possible through Php but i want to know that is this possible just by using JS and Html?

Comment: try to think that if html/js can save/edit a file, then you can hack someone's computer easily!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in localStorage ([here](http://geeknizer.com/html-5-client-storage/) is a page that'll help you get started). However it won't be completely permanent. Persistent yes, permanent no. The user can clear localStorage at any time, and even modify it with relative ease. Be careful how you use it, but it sounds like what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, you can not. HTML & JavaScript are just browser language while saving file is server task.

Comment: But JavaScript can let the browser save some data into a cookie or into localStorage!

Comment: As the asker said "permanently" then cookie & localStorage are out of circle. They're just good references.

Answer (score 0):

Try localStorage(depends on browser, about 5M) or cookie (about 4KB), but neither is persistent storage.